# How can user-defined annotations arbitrarily take some properties of the first few parameters instead of specifying some strings

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can user-defined annotations arbitrarily take some properties of the first few parameters instead of specifying some strings.
For example：
@ cacheable can use #p0 to represent the first parameter, and can #p0.* Value.

```
 @Cacheable(value = "aaaa",key = "#p0.id +'::'+#p0.name")
    public UserVoEntity getUserByRedisTimeObject(UserVoEntity vo) {
        return vo;
    }
```

How can my custom annotations achieve this

Comment: yes！  How do I implement my own annotations